# Obtaining record one before MAX(date) from table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, date

I have a table that stores all 12 months as a record, and two additional columns, processDate and completed. The processDate field is the date a process runs each month, this field gets updated once yearly. The other column 'completed' is Boolean changed to true when the process completes running on the date of processDate each month.

I have a max query that returns the processDate of all 12 records where completed is true.

What I would like is the date prior to the max(processDate)

```
SELECT MAX(processDate) FROM refreshProcessdates WHERE completed = 'True'
```

How can I return the record that is one less than the Max processDate, that being the month prior?

SQL Server Express 2008

Comment: Please clarify. The date of each month prior to the last execution or the date of the prior execution? If the later just add `AND processDate < (SELECT MAX(processDate) FROM refreshProcessdates WHERE completed = 'True')`

Comment: It is the date of the prior execution that is needed.

Comment: It worked, thank you, please add your comment as answer so that I can acknowledge as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to something like this. You just exclude the first result in the where clause.

```
 SELECT MAX(processDate) FROM refreshProcessdates WHERE completed = 'True' 
 AND processed date <> (SELECT MAX(processDate) FROM refreshProcessdates 
 WHERE completed = 'True')
```